# Nullpointer Exception While using Google 3D Pie Chart Tools?

Tags: android, image, http, bitmap

I am using this exact same code from here 
[Link](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/09/generate-3d-pie-chart-using-google.html)

to show 3D pie chart in my project .. The code is alright. I am getting the LOG of URL properly and when i use the link in browser its showing the chart properly .. But when i am trying to show the image to an image-view inside my application by converting it to bitmap , Its giving null pointer Exception ,,,

```
private Bitmap loadChart(String urlRqs){
  Bitmap bm = null;
  InputStream inputStream = null;

  try {
   **inputStream = OpenHttpConnection(urlRqs);
   bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
   inputStream.close();**
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return bm;
 }

 private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
  InputStream is = null;
  URL url = new URL(strURL);
  URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

  try{
   HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
   httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET";
   httpConn.connect();

   if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    is = httpConn.getInputStream(); 
   }
  }catch (Exception ex){
  }

  return is; 
 }
```

Comment: Try to make these calls in a AsyncTask

Comment: Could you help me with that ...

Comment: Thanx Mr A.S the problem is solved ..could you say how to change the color of the chart .. ???